# Delphi XE7: disable virtual text space

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7

is it possible to disable the annoying virtual space in editor?
If I click somewhere right on a line (behind last character) I want to get the cursor just behind the last character. Similary, if I am at the end of a line (just after the last char) and push right arrow I want to jump the next line before the first character.

Lot of thanks!

Comment: For instance CnPack has this feature (it is [`configurable here`](http://i.imgur.com/JB4ef1h.png)).

Comment: Do you really wish to disable one of the editor's main advantages? P.S. I don't know way to do it and I doubt if it exists outside custom extensions.

Comment: StS: yes, I really want. For me it is quite illogical since I am (mainly) a Visual Studio user. Simple sample situation: I forget to write a semicolon at the end of statement. I get compiler error and a highlited line. Now I have to take care where I'm going to click and write the semicolon instead of clicking somewhere behind the statement. Simly said - it requires more precision mouse navigation (or hitting End key).
You said one of main advantages - could you explain me what it is good for? Not trolling, I really want to know it (may be I will like it as well)

Comment: Well, for other people, Visual Studio is illogical regarding that point. It's a matter of how you look at things and what you are used to.

Comment: @JanDrozen For me the biggest advantage of this default behavior is that it makes spliting long lines into two or more much more easier. Imagine that you have a method that requires several parameters but you directly asign the result of other methods to these parameters instead of storing them in local variables first. This means that your command could quickly become to long to fit in the screen so you would want to split it into two lines. And since you want your code to be easily readable you would want that all the thext htat belongs to right side of command to form a parahraph ...

Comment: ... To achieve this in visual studio you would press ENTER when the line is becoming to long to form a new line and then use combination of TAB and SPACE key to get into right position so that continuation of your command would be below already existing right part of your command in previous line. To achieve this in Delphi you pres ENTER to form a new line and then use mouse to set editor carret to the position where you want to continue writing your code.

Comment: Similar can be achieved when you are spliting already written line of code that exceeds the width of the screen. All you have to do is create a new line using ENTER, select the part of line that you want to move to the next line and then simply drag it to desired position. Delphi will automatically add all necessary TAB and Space characters to fill the line before your dragged text. As far as I know this can't be done in VS but correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: As for quickly adding missing semicolon on the end of the line when the Delphi warns you on it. When the semicolon is missing Delphi will position its editor caret to the line below. So all you have to do is simply pres the Up Arrow key folowed by END and you are in corect position for adding mising semicolon. That is unless you have some comentary lines in between. But to tell you the truth I'm wondering why Delphi isn't designed in a way to automatically place editor carret where the semicolon is actually missing instead on the line below as it does now.

Comment: SilverWarior: OK, I understand you (and lot of other people) are familiar with this style.
My experience: If a method's signature has as many arguments as it does not fit the screen I used to write single argument per line. For me it's more readable than diffrent count if args on every line.
However, in VS you can enable/disable the virtual text space (default is disabled).